# OpenMesh convert Circulators to iterator

Tags: mesh, cgal, openmesh

I'm using OpenMesh, and try to iterate in BFS base on a vertex, I can get the neighbor of this vertex in the form of VertexVertexiterator,  but I want the neighbor in the form of Vertexitrator, how can I get it in this form, thanks~

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I do not see where CGAL comes in. You might have a look at http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/index.html as we have written specializations of the boost::graph_traits class for OpenMesh